# Combination of siunitx and light weight font fails to compile ...?

Tags: fonts, siunitx

### Question

I am trying to use the package `siunitx` in combination with the Opensans Light font. To make `siunitx` detect the font weight, I pass `\sisetup{detect-weight}`. However, the document fails to compile. Can anyone reproduce this behavior? Is there a workaround?

Thank you!

### Minimal example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight}

\begin{document}

\fontseries{l}\selectfont This is quite light: \SI{1}{\milli\gram}

\end{document}
```

### Edit 1

To clarify: replacing `\fontseries{l}` with `\fontseries{m}` or `\fontseries{b}` works as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `siunitx` assumes that for packages providing a 'light' font, the command `\lseries` will be defined in the same way as for `\mdseries`. Here, that is not the case. A suitable patch for text mode printing is

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\xpatchcmd{\__siunitx_detect_font_weight_text:}
  { \lseries }
  { \fontseries{l} \selectfont }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode = text}
\fontseries{l}\selectfont This is quite light: \SI{1}{\milli\gram}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or, maybe, `\DeclareRobustCommand\lseries{\not@math@alphabet\mdseries\relax\fontseries{l}\selectfont}`

Comment: @egreg Yes, perhaps that but I guess the package should be robust against this!

Comment: @egreg Any ideas for dealing with math mode in such a case?

Comment: I suppose you need to define a math version.